# Using a single get function for all models

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

So I have this bit of code in an extended model (MY_Model) in CodeIgniter:

```
function get($options = array(), $selects = array(), $joins = array(), $table, $object = TRUE)
{

    if(!empty($options))
    {
        foreach($options as $option => $array)
        {
            foreach($array as $column => $value)
            {
                $this->db->{$option}($column, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($select))
    {
        foreach($selects as $select)
        {
            $this->db->select($select);
        }
    }

    if(!empty($joins))
    {
        foreach($joins as $join => $array)
        {
            foreach($array as $jointable => $column)
            {
                $this->db->join($join, $join.'.'.$column.'='.$jointable.'.'.$column);
            }
        }
    }


    $query = $this->db->get($table);

    return $query->result();

}
```

Where I can pass it arrays like below:

```
    $options = array(
        'where' => array(
            'companys.companyID' => $companyID
        )
    );

    $select = array(
        'companyID',
        'companyName'
    );

    $join = array(
        'persons' => array(
            'companys' => 'companyID'
        )
    );

    $result = $this->companyModel->get($options, $select, $join, 'companys');

    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($result);
```

My question is, is there a reason why this isn't a good idea.  I extended the default CI_Model in my own MY_Model, and then all other model can use this get, and still have their own functions.  I have similar functions for the other basic CRUD actions.

Is the other way, of seperating functions in models to do most of the work and having the smallest controller possible the best route.  Even if that means your writing the same chucks of code over in all the models?

Hope it isn't a stupid question or I've misunderstood something core about MVC but thanks for the replies anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the long row of developers trying to abstract sql away. ;)

The Database abstraction is a core concept in web-applications, but is in no way a part of the MVC pattern since a Model is just described as a collection of data and methods that should reflect your domain. In reality this often means that there are business methods and callbacks to do just this. How you persist your data is up to you. Example patterns giving you some idea of whats should be done are  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx). Also take a look at Doctrine wich happens to use [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) in version 1.x and recently changed this in version 2.0 for a much simpler [Entity-Pattern](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/your-own-orm-doctrine2) with factorys.

Your method as is, looks fine to me. But there is a warning: Don't bend it to much. If you are writing an application and not a framework, you are free to embrace your domain not only in business but also in a technical aspect. If you find yourself handling querys that are not possible with this method, dont change the method but simply use a real query.